# OpenAPIv2(Swagger2) + GraphQL

Tags: graphql, openapi, swagger-codegen, graphql-java, openapi-generator

We have built a REST service which is documented using OpenAPIv2 specification.  We do code generation using swagger-codegen and build service on JAX-RS. 
We are looking to add GraphQL to our existing REST service. Looking for best possible way to integrate GraphQL into existing OpenAPI(Swagger)v2 spec.  Any help or directions is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tools should be able to generate GraphQL from your spec:

https://github.com/strongloop/oasgraph

or at least provide a good starting point.

Comment: Note that it got renamed to https://github.com/ibm/openapi-to-graphql but the above links redirects there anyway. The CLI described in the README will get you a GraphQL interface up and running in minutes if you have a well formed OAS or Swagger.